# How can I scroll down to read the full item descriptions?

Tags: doom-2016

I'm playing *Doom* on PC. When I read stuff in the in-game log, I can tell that there's more text, but I can't seem to actually scroll down to read it. The mouse scroll wheel doesn't work, clicking and dragging doesn't work, clicking on the scrollbar doesn't work, and mashing the keyboard hasn't worked.

[image]

I've discovered that if I plug in my gamepad, I can use the stick on that to scroll down. Is there any way to do this without plugging a gamepad in?

Comment: have you tried the down arrow? that works in some games

Answer (score 5, accepted):

click on the scroll bar to the right of the text, it should turn gray.  Then click on another tab to bring up different information, then click back on the tab you wanted to read.  The scroll bar should now appear correct and you should be able to click and drag the scroller down.

Comment: "on another tab" in case of the screenshot in OP that would be the word "Monsters". Clicking elsewhere did not work for me but clicking on "Monsters" in this case did.

Comment: It's a bug in the game.